# Best way to load multiple sprites to Image UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I'm new in Unity.
I need to dynamically create grid with UI elements who contain Image UI (  icon )  component.

I will put my main component in prefab folder and than I will dynamically load that prefab but I will need to change different sprite for every component in that grid.

My problem start when I need to change sprite of child Image component( icon  )
I don't know who is best way to dynamically load sprites and display it on Image UI component? Should I use Resources.Load or is thare any better way to do this ?

Thanka

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the sprite packer to save draw calls, you should not use the `Resources` folder; as it will break the sprite packer from working.

If you don't mind that, using `Resources` is fine for dynamic content.
Basically Unity will take anything you put in the resource folder and include it in your build (Whether you actually use it or not), once you access it; Unity will perform an I/O operation and load it for you.

If you need to download new content in the future, you should use the new `Addressables` system, which replaced assets bundles.